# shared preferences : float

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

something is wrong with it

```
package com.sahandxx3.Countries;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Setude on 17-Dec-15.
 */
public class Setting extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sh;
    TextView txtflag,txt_test;
    SeekBar sbflag;
    int progress = 10;
    float size=10;
    float txt_size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        init();
        txtflag.setText("Flag size : "+sbflag.getProgress());

        sbflag.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                txt_size=sh.getFloat("size",0);
                progress= i;
                size=(progress*5)+5;
                txtflag.setText("Flag size : "+progress);
                txt_test.setTextSize(size);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                txtflag.setText("Flag size : "+progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                txtflag.setText("Flag size : "+progress);
                sh=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Setting.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sh.edit();
                edit.putFloat("size",size);
                edit.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    private void init() {
        txtflag= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtflag);
        sbflag= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbflag);
        txt_test= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    }
}
```

so my problem is with this line:

```
 txt_size=sh.getFloat("size",0);
```

When I try to change the seekbar,It stops working.

then I want to use txt_size in txt_test();

Comment: _When I try to change the seekbar,It stops working._ What is error? Post error log.

Comment: You should be describing the error you are getting and what have you tried to fix it. Instead of writing nonsense you could paste your stack trace or explaining what is your problem (are you getting an uncaught exception, the seekbar is there and does not work correctly, etc)

Comment: No, not enough. Add the logcat of the error. Also, asking not to be downvoted typically ends in a downvote

Comment: @PiyushGupta my problem is solved now,Anyway,I can't use logcat for some reason.

Comment: @cricket_007 my logcat does not work while I'm using phone.

Comment: If you run the app from eclipse / android studio, it shouldn't matter what you are doing on the phone unless you unplug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that your `SharedPreferences` instance `sh` is null at the moment you try to access it. Try to move `sh=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Setting.this);` to your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Put below code on **onCreate()**:

```
sh=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Setting.this);
```

Your onCreate() method should looks like below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
sh=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Setting.this);

.. 
.. 

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: so sorry I can only accept one person and Orlangure answered earlier. :(

Comment: @Sahand.Setoodeh, no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
 float size=10f;
 txt_size=sh.getFloat("size",0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    sh=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}
```